# Codeanywhere Python3 Container doesn't have Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, codeanywhere

I am using a Python3 container and when I check the info, it says it has Python 3.5 installed. However, when I try to use the python3 command in the SSH terminal, it doesn't recognize it as a command. Further, when I use the python command, it says it has Python 2.6.6 installed, leading me to believe that it doesn't have Python3, only Python 2.6.6. I am new to Python and Codeanywhere, so I am just be forgetting something, but I can't find anything about it online.

Answer (score 0):

The Centos 7.2. Linux distributon (64 bit) has python 3.7